# Multivariate Regression with different predictors for each variable in R

Tags: r, time-series, regression, linear-regression, lm

I have a matrix `Y` of time series. The number of rows is the number of observations. I also have a matrix of predictors `X`. I want to regress columns of `Y` on predictors specific to these columns.
A logical matrix of 1's and 0's shows if the `i`-th variable should be regressed on the `j`-th predictor.

For instance:

```
y1 <- c(1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 3, 2, 1)
y2 <- c(5, 1, 3, 1, 3, 4, 5, 3)
y3 <- c(1, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 1, 2)
x1 <- c(2, 5, 4, 2, 1, 3, 6, 7)
x2 <- c(1, 5, 1, 3, 4, 2, 1, 3)

Y <- cbind(y1, y2, y3)
X <- cbind(x1, x2)

logical <- matrix(c(1,1,0,1,0,1), 3, 2)
lm <- lm(Y ~ ??? - 1)
```

Here, `y1` should be regressed on `x1` and `x2`, `y2` on `x1` only and `y3` on `x2` only.

I have tried to specify the model in the `lm` function but I have not been able to do so. In the `$coefficients` result, I would like "0"'s when a variable is not regressed on the `j`-th predictor.

Is it possible to do so without heavy dirty loops?

Comment: The `reformulate` function might make this a bit easier.

Comment: As I am a beginner I am still not very at ease with lapply(). Could you provide an example with the toy dataset above?

Comment: Ok ! I will do that with a for loop then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't do it with a single formula. You have to use a `for` loop, or `lapply()` to do this job. Have a go on this:

```
y1 <- c(1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 3, 2, 1)
y2 <- c(5, 1, 3, 1, 3, 4, 5, 3)
y3 <- c(1, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 1, 2)
x1 <- c(2, 5, 4, 2, 1, 3, 6, 7)
x2 <- c(1, 5, 1, 3, 4, 2, 1, 3)

flst <- c(y1 ~ x1 + x2, y2 ~ x1, y3 ~ x2)  ## formula list
lmlist <- lapply(flst, lm)  ## linear model list
```

You first collect all formula in a list, then use `lapply` to loop through them. In the end, you will have three linear models in the `lmlist`. Use `lmlist[[1]]` to extract the first one.

```
lmlist[[1]]
#Call:
#FUN(formula = X[[i]])

#Coefficients:
#(Intercept)           x1           x2  
#     4.2972      -0.6521       0.4592
```